# Same sequence number for two models, Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails Application, I have two models `Animal` and `Plant`, both have `sequence_id` column in table.
What I want is, Everytime a new `Animal` or `Plant` is created, It should have unique `sequence_id`.

**For example,**

Animal1 will have `sequence_id` 1

Animal2 will have `sequence_id` 2

Plant1 will have `sequence_id` 3

Animal3 will have `sequence_id` 4

Any Idea how to do this?

Is there any Rails way to do this?

Comment: Don't know what's unclear, but you could look here : https://github.com/ruuts/invoice_numbers (it was created for invoices but actually it could be used for something else)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new model called sequence. Both plant and animal should `belong_to` this model. You would do like this:

In both Model.rb files:

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
   #Do the same as below to animal.rb as well.
   belongs_to :sequence

   after_create :add_sequence_number

   ....

   def add_sequence_number
     self.sequence = Sequence.create!()
     self.save!
   end
end
```

Be sure to generate the sequence model like so `rails g model Sequence`, and make a migration where you add sequence to both Animal and Plant: `rails g migration AddSequenceToAnimal sequence_id:integer` and `rails g migration AddSequenceToPlant sequence_id:integer`.

Verify they add the line `add_column :animals, :sequence_id, :integer #or :plants` to the migration files.

Migrate.

Enjoy